# Перевод дробного числа в десятичной системе счисления в любую другую систему счисления

Tags: pascal

В чём может быть ошибка?

```
var a,c,ch: real;
    b:integer;
begin
  writeln('введите число');
  readln(a);
  writeln('введите основание ');
  readln(b);
  ch:=0;
  repeat
    c:= trunc(a);{отсекаем дробную часть}
    writeln('c=',c);{все выводы далее для контроля исполнения}
    a:=a-c;{отсекаем целую часть}
    writeln('a=',a);
    ch:=(ch+c)*10;{счётчик}
    writeln('ch=',ch);
    a:=a*b;{дробную часть умножаем на основание}
    writeln('a2=',a);
  until (a=0);{пока дробная часть не равна 0}
  writeln('0.',ch/10);{ответ}
end.
```

Суть программы: перевод дробного числа в десятичной системе счисления в любую другую систему счисления. При вводе числа в вычислениях происходит ошибка.

Пример работы:

```
введите число
0.5
введите основание 
2
c=0
a=0.5
ch=0
a2=1
c=1
a=0
ch=10
a2=0
0.1<==ответ;
(ошибок нет.)

введите число
0.9376
введите основание 
5
c=0
a=0.9376
ch=0
a2=4.688
c=4
a=0.688
ch=40
a2=3.44
c=3
a=0.439999999999999<==ошибка ломающая всё;
ch=430
```

Далее бесконечное выполнение программы, ответа нет.

Comment: паскаль это основа, более того для компиляции кодов на c и c++ нужны компиляторы, а их лицензии, как правило, платные, и школы на них тратится не хотят.

Comment: @typemoon если вы сможете переучить несколько десятков тысяч учителей и преподавателей на паскаля на Си - будет по вашему.

Comment: @globys GCC и QtCreator - превосходные компилятор и среда. Платить не надо.

Comment: я не знал, у меня то dev c++

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не разбираясь в коде могу предположить, что вы столкнулись со стандартной проблемой новичка - непониманием того как представлены в компьютерах числа с плавающей точкой (то что в Паскале называется real)

Суть проблемы в том что некоторые числа возможно представить точно и поэтому в ходе операций могут возникать числа вида 0.439999999999999

Т.е. по факту и по правилам школьной математики это 0.44 но для компьютера это разные числа.

Зная о такой особенности чисел с плавающей точкой при расчетах рекомендуется вместо непосредственного сравнения переменных использовать сравнение с некоторой дельтой.

Если взять ваш пример, то вместо сравнения a = 0 лучше использовать условие a < 0.0001

Т.е. условие отработает как только значение переменной приблизиться к нулю на определенную погрешность. В моем примере эта погрешность 0.0001  Как правило погрешность выбирается исходя из используемого алгоритма расчетов и исходя из того какая точность вычислений необходима.

Comment: а можно  как-нибудь отсечь лишнюю дробную часть. Что-то типа количество цифр после запятой - 4?

Comment: @globys можно и отсечь. Не помню Паскаль, поэтому не знаю есть ли там для этого специальная функция. Но в любом языке программирования это обычно решается тем что сначала число умножается на 10 в степени N. Потом от результата берется целая часть и она делится на 10 в степени N. N - это необходимое число знаков после запятой. В зависимости от того как берется целая часть возможно надо будет еще учитывать погрешность округления.

Comment: у меня к вам последний вопрос, если можно. Как убрать эту погрешность в вычислении? Она мешает выполнению программы.

Comment: @globys убрать нельзя. Это специфика компьютеров и представления чисел в двоичной форме

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> until (a=0);{пока дробная часть не равна 0}
> ```

Нельзя сравнивать дробные числа на равенство.
Следует выбрать некую погрешность и сравнивать модуль разности с ней.